# Django Queryset - Can I query at specific positions in a string for a field?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a table field with entries such as e.g. 02-65-04-12-88-55.

Each position (separated by -) represents something. (There is no '-' in the database, that's how it's displayed to the user).

Users would like to search by the entry's specific position. I am trying to create a queryset to do this but cannot figure it out. I could handle startswith, endswith but the rest - I have no idea.

Other thoughs would be to split the string at '-' and then query at each specific part of the field (if this is possible).

How can a user search the field's entry at say positions 0-1, 6-7, 10-11 and have the rest wildcarded and returned?

Is this possible? I may be approaching this wrong? Thoughts?

Comment: Regex querying may be what you're looking for (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex)

You would need to be careful with the actual regex to handle the number of characters and whatnot.

You may also use a combination of `contains` and `regex` to query what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use a `something__like='__-__-__-__-88-__'` query, but it's likely to not be very efficient (since the database will have to scan through all rows to find a match).

If you need to lots of these queries, it'd be better to split these out to actual fields (`something_1`, `something_2`, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will look at the first suggestion.

I can't really split the fields as this database is not going to change (it's been used for probably a few decades).

Comment: If you can't change the table, you can set up a secondary database of your choosing for faster queries, if it turns out to be a problem.